# How to further optimize a Convolutional Neural Network in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification

I'm trying to to classify bounding boxes in the COCO dataset. The best validation accuracy I'm currently getting is 60% on a subset of 8 classes (loss: 1.1541 - acc: 0.6028 - val_loss: 1.2102 - val_acc: 0.5893) after 15 epochs. The images which are used are converted to grayscale and resized to 64x64. The total number of photos that is used for training the model is 40604 and the validation set is a quarter/half of that.
the function to construct my neural network looks like :

```
def constructCNN(conv_layer, layer_size, kernel_size, dense_size, dense_layer, dropout, num_classes):
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (kernel_size, kernel_size), input_shape=trainset.shape[1:]))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

for l in range(conv_layer-1):
    model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (kernel_size, kernel_size)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
if(dropout):
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())

for j in range(dense_layer):
    model.add(Dense(dense_size))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
if(dropout):
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(num_classes))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    optimizer='adam',
    metrics=['accuracy'])

return model
```

I have tried the following configurations: dense_layers = [0,1,2,3], layer_sizes = [32,64,128], dense_sizes = [32,64,128], conv_layers = [1,2,3,4], kernel_sizes = [3,4], dropout = [True/False].

I also tried to use an ImageDataGenerator, but it didn't really improve my results.

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
featurewise_center=True,
featurewise_std_normalization=True,
zca_whitening=True, 
rotation_range=20,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)
```

I'm looking for suggestions that might improve the performance of my classifier.

Comment: You could try to employ attention in your network (https://skymind.ai/wiki/attention-mechanism-memory-network). I am not an image-classification expert but I can imagine that using three channels (RGB) as input might improve performance as well.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into it!